# Python 3.3: Output of Anagram Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def anagram(word,check):  
    for letter in word:  
        if letter in check:  
            check = check.replace(letter, '') 
        else:  
            return 0  
    return 1  


while True:
    f = open('dictionary.txt', 'r')
    try:
        user_input = input('Word? ')
        for word in f:
            word = word.strip()
            if len(word)==len(user_input):
                if word == user_input:
                    continue
                elif anagram(word, input):
                    print (word)
                    #try:
                        #if word == 1:
                            #print ('The only anagram for', user_input, 'is', word)
                        #elif word > 1:
                            #print ('The anagrams for', user_input, 'are', word)
                    #except TypeError:
                        #pass
    except EOFError:
        break
    f.close()
```

The function works as I want it to, but I need some help with the output. I want the output in one line, and the wording should reflect the amount of anagrams found. (i.e. 'only one anagram', 'the anagrams are', 'there are no anagrams', or 'the word is not in the dictionary') The comments in the code are what I have tried. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should probably be returning `True` and `False` in `anagram()`.

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but I suggest moving the `if len(word) == len(user_input)` and `if word == user_input` lines into the `anagram` function. "Are `word` and `check` the same length?" and "are `word` and `check` the same word?" Are logical questions to ask when checking for anagram-ness.

Comment: Also, I think you've got a bug somewhere because `anagram("aab", "baa")` returns 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand your program, you want to continuously prompt the user for words until he presses Ctrl-D (which results in an EOF error and breaks the loop)? In that case, you should read the file only once, before the beginning of the loop, and construct a list or set of the words in it. Also, your try/except statement should only contain the call to `input` as this is the only place where this exception can occur in your function.

Now on to your main question - to count the number of results and print different statements accordingly, just use a list comprehension to get a list of all anagrams of the input. Then you can count the anagrams and join them together to form an output string.

```
def find_anagrams():
    with open("dictionary.txt", "r") as fileInput:
        words = set(word.strip() for word in fileInput)

    while True:
        try:
            user_input = input("Word? ").strip()
        except:
            break  #you probably don't care for the type of exception here

        anagrams = [word for word in words if anagram(word, user_input)]
        print_results(anagrams)

def print_results(anagrams):
    if len(anagrams) == 0:
        print("there are no anagrams")
    elif len(anagrams) == 1:
        print("the only anagram is %s" % anagrams[0])
    else:
        print("there are %s anagrams: %s" % (len(anagrams), ', '.join(anagrams)))
```

The only thing missing from this code is cheking that the input word is not a part of the result list, but this can be moved to the `anagram` function. The function can also be simplified using the Counter class from the built-in collections module. This class is a dictionary-like object that can be constructed from an iterable and maps each object in the iterable to the number of its occurrences:

```
>>> Counter("hello") == {"h":1, "e":1, "l":2, "o": 1}
True
```

So we can rewrite the anagram function like this:

```
from collections import Counter

def anagram(word, check):
    return not word == check and Counter(word) == Counter(check)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a list with your results like this:

```
with open("dictionary.txt", "r") as fileInput:
    user_input = input("Search keyword: ").strip()

    listAnagrams = []
    for line in fileInput.readlines():
       for word in line.split(" "):
           if len(word) == len(user_input):
               if word == user_input:
                   continue
               elif anagram(word, user_input):
                   listAnagrams.append(word)

    if len(listAnagrams) == 1:
        print ('The only anagram for', user_input, 'is', listAnagrams[0])

    elif len(listAnagrams) > 1:   
        print ('The anagrams for', user_input, 'are', ", ".join(listAnagrams))

    else:
        print ('No anagrams found for', user_input)
```

Comment: if the `user_input` is short, would suggest generating all possible combinations of the input and simply checking which combinations exist in the file

Comment: Just a heads up - `raw_input` has been renamed to `input` in python3, the python2 `input` function has been removed.