# Python 3.3, finding anagrams?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program in Python that finds anagrams. Here is my current code:

```
def anagram(word,checkword):
    for letter in word:  
        if letter in checkword:  
            checkword = checkword.replace(letter, '') 
        else:  
            return False  
    return True  

while True:
    f = open('listofwords.txt', 'r')
    try:
        inputted_word = input('Word? ')
        for word in f:
            word = word.strip()
            if len(word)==len(inputted_word):
                if word == inputted_word:
                    continue
                elif anagram(word, inputted_word):
                    print(word)
                        #try:
                            #if word == 1:
                            #print ('The only anagram for', user_input, 'is', word)
                        #elif word > 1:
                            #print ('The anagrams for', user_input, 'are', word)
                        #except TypeError:
                            #pass
    except:
        break
```

I'm having trouble *outputting* the anagrams. The anagrams should be in one line, and the wording should reflect the amount of anagrams found. Such as...

> "There is only one (insert anagram) for (insert word inputted)"
>
> "There are (insert anagrams) for (insert word inputted)"
>
> "There are no anagrams for (insert word inputted)"
>
> "The (insert word inputted) is not in the dictionary")

Comment: we're not here to do your homework for you. What have you tried?

Comment: Okay, I edited the question. Comments in the code is what I've tried.

Comment: Your anagram() function will return true for any word that's part of another word, e.g. if you were checking 'cat' against 'thatcher', you would still get true . . . I'd suggest turning both words into lists and comparing the sorted lists.

Comment: Are you sure the sentences you've posted are really what your teacher wants? "There is only one 'god' for 'dog'" and "There are 'arm', 'ram' for 'mar'" and "The 'foobar' is not in the dictionary" are not very good sentences…

Comment: @ernie: Good point. But I get the feeling the `anagram` function came from the teacher, and it's really a "Scrabble helper" function rather than a real anagram function. (Maybe the teacher doesn't know English well enough to name it properly…)

Comment: You [already asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751838/python-3-3-output-of-anagram-function)?  You really shouldn't repost just because you don't like the answers . . .

Comment: @ernie My bad, totally forgot I asked this earlier this afternoon. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few hints:

First, if you have to print the count of anagrams before you print any of them, you need to hold onto a list of them while you're looping. Something like this:

```
anagrams = []
for word in f:
    word = word.strip()
    if len(word)==len(inputted_word):
        if word == inputted_word:
            continue
        elif anagram(word, inputted_word):
            anagrams.append(word)
```

Now you just have to figure out how to print the right text at the end, based on what's in the `anagrams` list.

As for what you tried:

```
#try:
    #if word == 1:
    #print ('The only anagram for', user_input, 'is', word)
#elif word > 1:
    #print ('The anagrams for', user_input, 'are', word)
#except TypeError:
    #pass
```

This can't possibly work. First, `word` is a word, so it can't possibly be equal to `1`, or greater than `1`. Also, if you've only gone through, say, the first 20 words in the dictionary, and found the first anagram, how could you know that this is the only anagram? There may be 1000 of them in the rest of the dictionary. You can't decide which sentence to print until you've finished the whole dictionary.

Meanwhile, notice that you have different cases for "There is only one" vs. "not in the dictionary". So, you need some kind of flag for "found inputted_word in the dictionary", which you set inside that `if` statement. Or maybe, you could just leave the special case out—for example, at the end, if you have 0 results, you know it was not in the dictionary. It depends on whether you want more logic at the end, or inside the loop.